# Is it possible to connect to one VPN by temporary connecting to the other (due to the regional blockage of the first one)?

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, openvpn

I have access to 2 VPN services: A via application — paid and unlimited and B via openvpn file (ovpn) — free but limited. The problem is that ISP blocks A but not B (well, some ovpn files do work and some don't).

First of all, I think it's impossible (without trickery) to connect to one VPN through another and then cut the first/outer connection while still using the second/inner. But it just so happened that I kinda did this, at least once. But perhaps I was just lucky that after cutting the connection with B the connection with A restored anyway (IP wasn't blocked). Anyway, that's just my rational argument.

But is it possible to use B to connect to A and then disconnect from B while still connected to A? If it's realistically not possible, is it possible at all (now I'm just curious)? Which protocols can achieve that? Of course, I don't have any access to VPNs except from using an app for A and ovpn file for B. So no terminal, no SSH, no nothing.

P.S. I definitely haven't mastered all the networking stuff, but I'm using a Linux distro (as a coder) for a long time and I do know (I think) a lot of basics/concepts, including about VPN.

Comment: See [How to bypass VPN blocks & make your VPN undetectable](https://cybernews.com/how-to-use-vpn/bypass-vpn-blocks/). If one of these many methods works for you, let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, what you are trying to achive does not work.

In layman's terms: once you collapse (the outer) VPN tunnel all connections establised via this tunnel are collapsed as well. Think of the tunnel as an "extention" of your network interface. If you connect to a web server via the VPNs it looks sort of like that:

```
[YOU]<--->[VPN B]<--->[VPN A]<--->[WebServer]
```

Once you break the connection to VPN B the connection to A is lost as well, and if you reconnect without VPN B it becomes a whole differnet connection and therefore everything has to be reestablished:

```
[YOU]<--->[VPN A]<--->[WebServer]
```

Comment: Well, at least I was right. Thank you. But I had one hypothetical thought: can I send a message to VPN A through VPN B to "call me later" after I disconnect from B? It will be probably much, much more complicated because (I think) I would have to deploy my own server (on my machine) and VPN A would act as a client which wants to connect to my server. Would it work, or VPN A's IP will be still blocked (if the direction of connection would change)? I never actually thought of that.

Comment: @Andrew15_5 No, you'll have the same issue there, again in layman's terms: the VPN A network "knows" that the VPN B end point established a connection, it doensn't know you since you are "behind" the VPN B network. But even if this would be a existing feature, if your ISP block outgoing traffic to certain IP ranges (assuming your assumption is correct) how do you know it won't block incoming traffic from those IP ranges as well?

Comment: @Andrew15_5 It's great that you are aware of accepting/voting, thanks! It was just a friendly reminder since a lot of people forget about accepting/voting, sometimes including myself. Not meant to be impatient, sorry if you got this vibe. Please feel free to take as much time as you need! Gald my answer was helpful to you (I would suggest to delete these comments since they are off topic in regards to the question/answer).